# evaluate pattern stored in variable perl regexp

Tags: regex, perl, variables, eval, match

I am trying to find out if basket has apple [simplified version of a big problem]

```
$check_fruit = "\$fruit =~ \/has\/apple\/";
$fruit="basket/has/mango/";
if ($check_fruit) {
       print "apple found\n";
}
```

check_fruit variable is holding the statement of evaluating the regexp.
However it check_fruit variable always becomes true and shows apple found :(

Can somebody help me here If I am missing something.

Goal to accomplish:
Okay so let me explain:

1. I have a file with a pattern clause defined on eachline similar to:

   ```
   Line1: $fruit_origin=~/europe\\/finland/ && $fruit_taste=~/sweet/ 
   Line2: similar stuff that can contain ~10 pattern checks seprated by && or || with metacharacters too
   ```

2.I have another a list of fruit attributes from a perl hash containing many such fruits

3 I want to categorize each fruit to see how many fruits fall into category defined by each line of the file seprately.

Sort of fruit count /profile per line Is there an easier way to accomplish this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Easiest answer is that as `$check_fruit` is a string with content, it will always be true.

Comment: Can you give some more context?  Where did this file come from?  Where do the variables like `$fruit_origin` get set?  It seems like a very strange way of solving a simple problem of categorizing and counting.

Comment: Also, this is not valid Perl code: `$fruit_origin=~/europe/finland/`.  Perl will treat the `/` in the middle as ending the pattern match.  Is that an actual example of what your file contains?

Comment: @dan1111, yes u r correct, its not a valid perl code. Corrected now.
Unfortunately I don't have any control over how this file is dumped. This is just one of my inputs.

Comment: Assuming the checks are separated with && or ||, and are of the format `$foo =~ /bar/`, it might be safest to split and parse it. The brute force way.

Comment: Yeah, that might be a solution. But I wanted to avoid that :)
thanks anyways

Answer (score 2):

`if ($check_fruit)` returns true because $check_fruit is defined, not empty and not zero. If you want to evaluate its content, use `eval`. But a subroutine would serve better:

```
sub check_fruit {
    my $fruit = shift;
    return $fruit =~ m(has/apple);
}

if (check_fruit($fruit)) {
    print "Apple found\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I cannot split the contents of check_fruit variable as problem is not that simple for me. Basically check_fruit will be a series of regexp match clauses [seprated by && or ||].
I wished if the check_fruit variable which contains clauses for pattern match can be evaluated directly as I get this variable in form of a string [which will be having meta -characters too-> that I might need to do back escape]. I hope u got my point :)

Comment: @mantupandey, maybe a question asking about your real task would be appropriate.

Comment: @mantu Sounds like an XY-problem to me. Ask about your goal, rather than about the problems with your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a need to store the statement in a variable? If you're sure the value isn't set by a user, then you can do

```
if (eval $check_fruit) {
```

but this isn't safe if the user can set anything in that expression.

Comment: I need to have the statement in variable as this is my input from a file which defines pattern clauses: what regexp check needed and on which variables. Lemme try this

Comment: Didn't work :(
Code:
        $check_fruit = "\$fruit =~ \/has\/apple\/";
        $fruit="basket/has/mango/";
        if ($check_fruit) {
            print "apple found\n";
        }


Error:
 ./example.pl
Bareword found where operator expected at (eval 1) line 1, near "/has/apple"
        (Missing operator before apple?)
Unquoted string "apple" may clash with future reserved word at (eval 1) line 1.

Comment: @mantupandey, this is due to other problems with your code.  See my answer for a full working example.

Answer (score 0):

Put the pattern (and only the pattern) into the variable, use the variable inside the regular expression matching delimiters `m/.../`. If you don't know the pattern in advance then use `quotemeta` for escaping any meta characters.

It should look like this:

```
my $check_fruit = '/has/apple/'; # here no quotemeta is needed
my $fruit       = 'basket/has/mango/';
if ($fruit =~ m/$check_fruit/) {
  # do stuff!
}
```

Comment: Please refer comment above. Thanks 4 reply :)

Comment: Whose comment are you referring to? Keep in mind that the order in which you see the answers doesn't have to be the order in which I see them currently.

Comment: ohh, please see my latest reply to dan1111

Answer (score 0):

`$check_fruit` is nothing but a variable holding string data.  If you want to execute the code it contains, you have to use `eval`.

There were also some other errors in your code related to string quoting/escaping.  This fixes that as well:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $check_fruit = '$apple =~ m|/has/mango|';
my $apple="basket/has/mango/";

if (eval $check_fruit) {
       print "apple found\n";
}
```

However, this is not usually a good design.  At the very least, it makes for confusing code.   It is also a huge security hole if `$check_fruit` is coming from the user.  You can put a regex into a variable, which is preferable:

*Edit: note that a regex that comes from user input can be a security problem as well, but it is more limited in scope.*

```
my $check_fruit = qr|/has/mango|;
my $apple="basket/has/mango/";

if ($apple =~ /$check_fruit/) {
       print "apple found\n";
}
```

There are other things you can do to make your Perl code more dynamic, as well.  The best approach would depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Okay so let me explain:
1. I have a file with a pattern clause defined on eachline similar to:
    Line1: $fruit_origin=~/europe/finland/ && $fruit_taste=~/sweet/
    Line2: similar stuff that can contain ~10 pattern checks seprated by && or || with metacharacters too


2. I have another a list of fruit attributes from a perl hash containing many such fruits
3. I want to categorize each fruit to see how many fruits fall into category defined by each line of the file seprately. Sort of fruit count /profile per line 

Is there an easier way to accomplish this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @mantu You should add new info to your question by editing it.